# InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [28,1] vs. [32,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow

Disclaimer: I did find similar questions, but none of the answers helped me.

The problem I'm working on is a regression problem - the inconsistent shape in the question is for the labels.

The batch size inputed is 32, which is not hardcoded while creating placeholders for inputs and label. I even cut the size (number of samples) of the data to the nearest multiple of batch size (which should not be necessary in the first place - just tried my luck). I still get the inconsistency in shape error - not every time I run the program, though - once in 5 times the program runs without any error

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to supply a self-contained minimal failing example. There is a 20% chance that you will figure out what the problem is while in the process of typing it out. We need some concrete code either way plus version numbers of Python and the library and ideally the output of the stack trace as well.